# is there any solution for importing request library in django using python?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to link my python code in Django and as I'm using an API for weather and using it to extract the data for any country.

I want to use a location, date, format and tp from the API link. The problem is that I don't know how to extract those 4 four things particular from the same link. It showing me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muahr\source\repos\RCAI-Project\Pest\api.py", line 14, in <module>
    url=int(api_address+city+24+date_time)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

At the same time, I'm integrating this whole code into the Django and it's giving me an error that request isn't defined.

Original Code:

```
import requests
import simplejson
import time
from daytime import DateTime    
api_address='http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=abc123&q=&format=json&date=&tp=24'
city=input("enter\n")
ask=input("enter date\n")
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
date_time = datetime.strptime(ask, date_format)
url=int(api_address+city+24+date_time)
json_data=requests.get(url).json()
formatted_data=json_data['data']
print(json_data)
```

Comment: This question doesn't have *anything at all* with using requests, or Django. Why are you trying to convert your URL into an int? What would that even mean? Why are you appending an int (24) to a string (the rest of your URL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

city = input("enter city\n")
date = input("enter date\n")
json_data = requests.get(
    'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx',
    params=dict(
        key='abc123...',
        q=city,
        format='json',
        date=date,
        tp='24'
    )
).json()
formatted_data = json_data['data']
print(formatted_data)
```

Problems with the code:

```
date_time = datetime.strptime(ask, date_format)
url=int(api_address+city+24+date_time)
```

1. You cannot concatenate a str, int, and datetime with `+`. They must all be strings.
2. You could convert them to strings first, but since your datetime started as a string from `input` you just don't need to parse it to begin with.
3. The result would obviously not be convertible to an int.
4. You wouldn't want an int for a URL.
5. The result would still be far from a properly formatted URL with `&` and `=` in the right places to denote the parameters. `+` will not magically insert the parameters where you want them. You would need to do this:

```
url = ('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?key=abc123&q='
        + city + '&format=json&date=' + ask + '&tp=24')
```

6. The above is not great. `requests` can take care of this for you with `params`.